# User creation with stripe subscription

Tags: rust, stripe-payments

I'm currently building a website to sell subscription based services.
Currently, the user creation form is like a usual registration form (e-mail and password) + choice of subscription tier. On submit, I send the user information (e-mail and password) to the backend and store them as an inactive user and then redirect the user to the stripe payment page using the link that stripe provides for each product (note that that form requires an e-mail).

I have a stripe webhook that listens for paymentintent.succeeded events (and other events to handle unsubscription, payback and other stuff), and if the e-mail that I get in the webhook event matches an inactive account, that account becomes active and has access to the functionalities according to the tier the user chose. While this would work if the user uses the same e-mail for the registration and in the stripe form, it would fail otherwise (that is, if for some reason the user uses different e-mails), and the procedure does not feel very robust.
I was wondering if there is a more robust way to obtain the same result (user creation + verification of correct payment). The backend is written in Rust using actix + async-stripe, if that matters. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [SO] your question is actually a design decision question:

"***While this would work if the user uses the same e-mail for the registration and in the stripe form, it would fail otherwise (that is, if for some reason the user uses different e-mails), and the procedure does not feel very robust.***"

[SO] is not the right forum for it.  But to tell you why what you are trying to do is not a good idea, consider same user wanting two different accounts (e.g. paid by same CC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the stripe payment page using the link that stripe provides for each product (note that that form requires an e-mail).

I'm guessing you mean either Stripe Checkout or Payment Links here.
Both solutions allow you to prefill the email:
-Using the `customer_email` argument with Checkout Sessions:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#prefill-customer-data
-Using the `prefilled_email` query param with Payment Links:
https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info#customize-checkout-with-url-parameters
(Note that with this one, the customer can actually change the value of the field still)

Without prefilling the email, it seems like you're doing the same process twice:
-Registering / logging the user in to their account.
-Collecting the email again on the Session.
I think prefilling the email would help streamline your flow.

Comment: The issue is that I needed a field to "tie together" the user creation and the payment to verify that that user payment succeeded. Payment links with prefilled emails won't work as the e-mail may be changed, Checkout sessions appear to be more complex than payment links but I think that will work, the server would generate a checkout session and redirect to its url. Thank you for your answer.